# python One hot encoding for comma separated values

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

my dataset looks like this

```
Type   Date         Issues
M      1 Jan 2019   A12,B56,C78
K      2 May 2019   B56, D90
M      5 Feb 2019   A12,K31 
K      3 Jan 2019   A12,B56,K31,F66
.
.
.
```

I want to do one hot encoding for the issues column

so my dataset looks like this

```
Type   Date         A12 B56 C78 D90 E88 K31 F66
M      1 Jan 2019   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
K      2 May 2019   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
M      5 Feb 2019   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
K      3 Jan 2019   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
.
.
.
```

How to do that in Python

Comment: What you want is not called one-hot encoding, I don't know its proper name though.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: We expect you to make an honest attempt, not merely post your coding assignment.

Comment: Is this `pandas.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.concat([df.drop('Issues', 1), df['Issues'].str.get_dummies(sep=",")], 1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Type        Date   D90  A12  B56  C78  F66  K31  K31 
0    M  1 Jan 2019     0    1    1    1    0    0     0
1    K  2 May 2019     1    0    1    0    0    0     0
2    M  5 Feb 2019     0    1    0    0    0    0     1
3    K  3 Jan 2019     0    1    1    0    1    1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your issues are concatenated together into strings, you can do it like this:

```py
# Get a list of the issues
issues = sorted(set(",".join(df.Issues).split(",")))

# Fill columns with 0's and 1's
for issue in issues:
    df[issue] = df.Issues.str.contains(issue).astype(int)
```